# Make new dataframe from top 3 values per group

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, select

I want to make a new dataframe from the top 3 rows for the 'value' column for each 'gr'. So basically a dataframe with the top 3 'values' for 'gr' 1,2,3,4,5 in the example below.

Here is an example dataset:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                          gr = c("5","3","3","5","5","5","5","3","5","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","4","4","4","4","4","4"),
                          value = c("20.06915","20.06915","19.53556","19.39911","19.06339","18.35938","18.34701","17.85767","17.60714","17.30706","17.08515","16.91452","16.72728","16.46812","15.85850","15.42839","14.92798","14.65943","14.53258","14.33954","14.33583","14.23938","14.19658","14.12557","14.03669","13.89811","13.78137","13.75599","13.51798","13.41058","13.17932","13.11952","12.67316","12.57049","11.88663","11.08443","10.75299","10.61885","10.40393"))
```

Many thanks
Cheers

Comment: `dataframe %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  top_n(3, value)
` using `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create a function that gives us the top n rows:

```r
top_n <- function(x, n = 3L) {
  x[head(order(x$value), n = n), ]
}
```

Using base R, we could use `by()` and `rbind()` the returned list:

```r
res <- by(dataframe, dataframe$gr, top_n)
do.call(rbind, res)
```

Using `data.table`, we can achieve the same with more concise syntax:

```r
data.table::setDT(dataframe)
dataframe[, top_n(.SD), by = "gr"]
```